# Last of the OpenID users - Stranded!

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, accounts, openid

Let me start by saying that even being able to ask this question took a fair amount of effort -- I had to create a new account, [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504274/outlook-vba-efficiency-of-regex-in-outlook-vba) on SO, and then wait agonizing hours till someone upvoted it and I had the requisite 5+ reputation on SO to be able to ask a question on Meta SO.

Anyway, I digress.

I was a (happy) OpenID user (authentication provider: yahoo.com), and had multiple accounts across the SE network -- here is my SO profile, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414455/tchakravarty.

Now I know I should have heeded the multiple emails about the deprecation of OpenID accounts, but I didn't, and lo, one day, I found that I was in a weird limbo state between being logged in and not being logged in.

For example, when I land on the SO homepage, I am asked to "Join the Community":

[image: Join the Community]

I click on "Confirm new account":

[image: Confirm new account]

And bam!

[image: Something bad]

The weirdest part of this is that I still am logged in with my old account to some of my other network sites, such as stats.SE and am able to do all the things that I would usually be able to do on there (such as ask questions, edit my old answers) -- in fact, when someone upvotes one of my old **SO** answers, I still get a notification for that. It is just on SO that I am unable to either use my old account for creating new questions, answering or voting, nor log in with a new one.

This account was created, and logged in to in Incognito mode. I need help to access my old account on SO and to migrate it to a new authentication provider. Any help would be welcome.

Happy to provide any further information here.

Comment: Have you tried adding another login method on one of the sites where you're logged in?

Comment: The OpenID login form ceased working 2 to 3 months after the announced end of support. You're going to have to https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: @TheWanderer I did indeed -- I added an email based login (I can provide a screenshot) and I tried adding a Gmail login, but that "did not take". In either case, I am not sure how to use these additional logins, given that I am always asked to "Join the community", not login, and when I try to join the community, I am never asked for a choice of which credentials to use to login.

Comment: Clear your cookies.

Comment: @TheWanderer If I clear my cookies, won't I lose my stats.Se login? That really is my biggest fear.

Comment: You already have an email login added, so just use that if you need to. But browsers let you clear cookies per-domain, so try clearing just SO cookies first.

Comment: @TheWanderer PS. Another thing that I just tried is to log out, and then try to log back in using the email-based (same email as OpenID: yahoo.com) login that I had created -- and I got the same "Something bad happened" screen as in the text of this question.

Comment: Do what mario told you in the second comment. Use the "contact us" option because that user profile seems to be in a state you can't resolve yourself. I suspect It needs a dev to poke the tables in the database. The contact us route also opens a private channel between you and SE staff in case they need extra confirmation and checks to guarantee they are merging the right accounts.

Comment: Use the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) link to put in a formal request to have the old account merged into your new one. Explain that you don't have full access to the old one because of the OpenID issue.

Comment: @rene Next time I have to munge DB data to fix an issue, I'm going to refer to it as "poking the tables".

Comment: By the looks of things you have at least two network accounts anyway... one that is the linked SO one, then another which is your stats.se account. You might want to mention that when you contact SE, so that they give you access to the right one(s)?

Comment: Pro-tip: next time make a few good edits with your sock account, should be more reliable and even quicker to enter meta that way.

Comment: Another Pro-tip is to use incognito mode of the browser to check if you can relogin without having to clear the cookies on your preferred browser before knowing it will work.

Comment: _"Now I know I should have heeded the multiple emails about the deprecation of OpenID accounts, but I didn't, and lo, one day"_ Yeah you lost me here, sorry. (Kidding a bit - this is definitely a bug! Seriously though, why did you wait after being warned repeatedly? o.O)

Answer (score 6):

You actually did listen to our emails about OpenID deprecation (albeit still later). You attempted to add a Google credential to your account back in October. But, that Google account was already connected to another network account, so the system went through its merge routine. Because of your account status (> 1,000 reputation), that merge wasn't allowed to go through. But it did *something* and seemed to have failed in a rather strange way.

The failed merge left your Stack Overflow profile mapped to the second network account that it tried to merge into, with no Stack Overflow profile mapped to this network account. You were being shown the create new profile screen because it didn't see a profile connected to your account. Trying to actually do so fails because you actually do already have a profile so it won't let you create another.

We remapped your Stack Overflow profile back to its correct network account, and merged your newly created account here with it to attach the credential.

This still leaves *another* network account out there with the other Google account you tried to add back in October. If you'd still like to merge those together, feel free to [contact us](/contact) and request a merge.